# Show that $C([a,b])$ is complete

Tags: general-topology, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $C([a,b]) =\{f:[a,b] \to R |$f is continuous} with the supremum norm. Show that $C([a,b])$ is complete.

I want to show that if $(f_1,f_2,...)$ is a Cauchy sequence, then it is convergent. I already showed that $f(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$ exists. Then it is sufficient to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \|f-f_n\|_\infty =0$

So I got $\|f-f_n\|_\infty=sup\{|f(x)-f_n(x)| |x \in [a,b]\}$, I think I must use the property of compactness of $[a,b]$ but I don't know where and how to use it.

Comment: You do not need to use the compactness of $[a,b]$..... Theorem:  If $(X,d)$ and $(Y,e)$ are metric spaces and if  $(f_n)_n$ is a sequence of continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$ that converges uniformly to $f:X\to Y $, then $ f$  is continuous.... Here, $X=C[0,1]$  and $Y=\Bbb R$ . And if $(f_n)_n$ is Cauchy then $(f_n(x))_n$  converges to a value $f(x)$ for each $x\in [0,1]$ (..because $\Bbb R$ is complete.) It is not hard then to show that $f_n\to f$  uniformly, using the definition of the metric on $C[0,1].$.

Comment: The compactness of $[a,b]$ is irrelevant. If $X, Y$ are metric spaces, a uniform limit  $f$ of a uniformly convergent sequence $(f_n)_n$ of continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Given $\epsilon>0$, there is $N$ such that $\|f_n-f_m\|<\epsilon$
for all $n$, $m\ge N$. Show that $\|f_n-f\|\le\epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$, etc.

Comment: You do need to remark (as a known lemma? I don't know what the OP already knows) that the pointwise "candidate" limit is indeed continuous as well, to be in the space at all.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_1, f_2, \dots, f_n, \dots \in C([a,b])$ be a cauchy sequence (with the $\sup$ norm). For any fixed $x \in [a,b]$ and $i,l \in \mathbb{N}$, it holds that:
$$
|f_i(x) - f_l(x)| \leq \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f_i(x) - f_l(x)|
$$
Hence (for a fixed $x$) the sequence $f_n(x)$ is cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$ and converges since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete. Let us denote this limit by $f(x)$ i.e. $f(x) \triangleq \lim_{n} f_n(x)$.

It remains to prove two things. First we prove that $f_n$ converges to $f$ with the $sup$ norm. Finally we prove that $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous hence in $C[a,b]$. (Interestingly none of these will require the compactness of [a,b] and the following arguments hold if $[a,b]$ is replaced by any metric space)

Proof of $\sup$-norm covergence: Let $\epsilon>0$ Since $f_n$ is cauchy there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. for all $i,j \geq N$:
$\|f_i-f_j \|_\infty = \sup_{x \in [a,b]} (f_i(x)-f_j(x)) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$

Moreover since $f(x) = \lim_{n} f_n(x)$, for each $x \in [a,b]$ there exists $m =m(x) \in \mathbb{N}$ (dependent on x) such that:
$|f_{m(x)}(x)-f(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$

And without loss of generality one may assume that $m(x) \geq N$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Putting these two together it holds that for all $n \geq N$ and any $x \in [a,b]$:

$|f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq |f_n(x)-f_{m(x)}(x) | + |f_{m(x)}(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon  $

Since this result holds for any $x \in [a,b]$ it follows that for all $n \geq N$:

$\|f_n - f\|_\infty <\epsilon$

i.e. $f_n$ converges to $f$ in the sup -norm.

Proof of continuity: Let $x_0 \in [a,b]$. We prove $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.Let $\epsilon >0$. Let $y\in [a,b]$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary. Then by triangle inequality we have:
$|f(x_0)-f(y)| \leq |f(x_0) - f_n(x_0)| + |f_n(x_0)-f_n(y)| + |f_n(y) - f(y)|\leq \|f_n-f\|_\infty + |f_n(x_0)-f_n(y)| + \|f_n-f\|_\infty $

Pick $N$ large enough such that $\|f_N-f\|_\infty < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$. Since $f_N$ is continuous it holds that there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $y$ such that $|y-x_0|<\delta$,

$|f_N(y)-f_N(x_0)| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$

Hence for all $y$ such that $|y-x_0|<\delta$ it holds that:

$|f(x_0)-f(y)| < \|f_N-f\|_\infty + |f_N(x_0)-f_N(y)| + \|f_N-f\|_\infty $ < \epsilon